# Best way to child proof a house?

Tags: child-safety

First child is on the way, and aside from placing locks on cabinets and fences around the pool, what are the top ways I can child proof the more dangerous parts of the house?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Sorry, but that question is far too broad. The sheer number of situations and  solutions make it a poor fit for SE. Also, there are probably countless articles already available on New Mommy & Daddy sites.

Answer (score 1):

Pad sharp edged fixtures and furniture, like slate fireplace hearths and metal/glass furniture (I used split foam pipe insulation). Install safety plugs in your electrical receptacles. Put a latch on the toilet seat to prevent small toys from being flushed. Install latching gates to restrict stairway access. Place latches on shower doors/sliding glass tub enclosures.

Sell your motorcycle. Sell your 1968 Pontiac Firebird and buy a mini-van. Give up poker night with the boys. Learn sleep deprivation coping strategies. Start saving for baby's college tuition. Jump off a bridge...

Comment: Most life insurance doesn't cover suicide, so jumping off a bridge would not benefit your family at all. If you're having bad thoughts, please call 1-800-273-8255, or use the [online chat service](http://chat.suicidepreventionlifeline.org/GetHelp/LifelineChat.aspx) provided by the National Suicide Prevention Lifeline.